# Is this question worded correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I'm trying to solve some questions in dynamics and I came across this problem. I've attempted to solve it first without looking at the answer but after several attempts, I've failed. I've looked at the answer and I found out two cases:

1. the question is poorly worded.
2. There is hidden details I couldn't extract from the question.

As you can see from the problem, the question is to determine the distance travelled by car A when they pass each other. The car A first travels with constant acceleration and then travels with constant speed. The author assumes implicitly the car A will pass car B when car A travels with a constant speed. How can I, as a student, infer this from the question?

[image]

Comment: You can't directly say that. You've to take cases i.e. solve by hit and trail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following may be useful to consider.

The distance that car A travels during the accelerating portion is computed as $533.33$ ft.  During that same amount of time, $13.33$ seconds, car B will have traveled $13.33 \times 60 = 799.8$ feet.  Since car A and B are 6000 feet apart at $t=0$, then they will still be $6000-799.8-533.33=4666.87$ feet apart after $13.33$ seconds.  Therefore, the conclusion must be that they pass each other when car A is in the constant velocity portion.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nicely done, so it seems to me, the solution must include the info you've provided at least to show students that they need to be careful when they analyze such problems. I hate when authors skip crucial details.